# MYSQL 5.5: Limit to size of subquery results

Tags: mysql, subquery

I use the following SELECT to return a multi-level JSON object:

```
        SELECT CONCAT('{"f":{', GROUP_CONCAT(facetgroups ORDER BY labelpos), '}}') INTO p_facets
    FROM  (
          SELECT labelpos,tcount,CONCAT('"', label, '":{', GROUP_CONCAT(facet ORDER BY tcount DESC,sfvdata),'}') AS facetgroups
          FROM ( 
                SELECT labelpos,label,count(item) AS tcount,sfvid,sfvdata,
                    CONCAT('"', sfvid, '":{"d":"',sfvdata,'","c":',count(item),',"i":"',GROUP_CONCAT(item),'"}') AS facet
                FROM (
                     SELECT 
                      fg.position AS labelpos,
                      fg.name AS label,
                      i.id AS item,
                      sfv.id AS sfvid,
                      CPCF_TO_BASE64(sfv.data) as sfvdata
                     FROM cpctu_item AS i
                     JOIN cpctu_accesspoint AS ap ON ap.item_id = i.id
                     JOIN cpctu_marcfield as m ON m.id = ap.marcfield_id        
                     JOIN cpctu_subfieldvalue as sfv ON m.id = sfv.marcfield_id
                     JOIN cpct_subfield as sf ON sf.id = sfv.subfield_id
                     JOIN cpct_filtergroup as fg ON fg.id = sf.filtergroup_id
                     WHERE i.id IN (SELECT item_id FROM searchresult)
                     AND (  sfv.tagindex LIKE "1__.a"
                         OR sfv.tagindex LIKE "260.a"
                         OR sfv.tagindex LIKE "260.b"
                         OR sfv.tagindex LIKE "260.c"
                         OR sfv.tagindex LIKE "490.a"
                         OR sfv.tagindex LIKE "6__.a")
                     ) AS SQ1
              GROUP BY label, sfvdata   
              ORDER BY labelpos
             ) AS SQ2
      GROUP BY label ORDER BY label 
        ) AS SQ3;
```

The high level structure of the resulting object can be seen in the following image:

[image]

I have group_concat_max_len set to 4Mb.

In MYSQL version 5.7.28, I have not hit any limits to the size of the strings produced at any level in the SELECT. For instance, the image above is of a well-formed JSON object weighing in at about 250Kb, with individual elements in the top level coming in at over 80Kb. Given that the only field in the top level SELECT is a CONCAT() string, this implies that CONCAT in this MYSQL version can handle 250Kb+ without objection.

I have had to deploy this QUERY to a site using MYSQL 5.5.47, and find that the results of the subqueries are truncated. For the same query that delivers a 250Kb object in 5.7.28, I now get a malformed object of about 86K in which each element elements in the top level is truncated at 16384 bytes. Given that the top level CONCAT() string is 86K, this is obviously not a limitation of CONCAT, so I assume it is a limitation of the size of the string that can be returned from a subquery.

I cannot find any documentation of this limitation. I have searched the Server System Variables in

[MySQL v5.5 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.5-en/server-system-variables.html)

for anything with a 16384 limit, but can't find anything that looks relevant. Can anyone throw any light on this?

Comment: That's horrendous. Could you it use some application level code to generate the json?

Comment: That is not the point of the question. Anyway, why is it horrendous? It is fast and effective. The question is about mysql, not my coding style,

Comment: Because in application code (php, for example), all of that could be reduced to `json_encode(my_data)`

Comment: @strawberry, if generating JSON from the database is so horrendous, why have the MYSQL team caught up in V8 and added so much JSON functionality, some of which lets you generate JSON result sets much as I am doing - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html

Comment: I'd be interested to see the query result set that would produce a 5-level-deep JSON object with one pass through json_encode().

Comment: So you can store and retrieve json, I guess. I don't see that the positions are mutually exclusive

Comment: Manipulating multi-dimensional arrays is a breeze in application code

Comment: do you have an answer to my question about subquery limitations?

Comment: It's pretty clear that I reject the premise of the question, but no, I don't.

Comment: "so I assume it is a limitation of the size of the string that can be returned from a subquery" - which would be quite simple to test.